# Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python

```
    while len(password)<6 or len(password)>12:
password = input("enter a password that is between 6 and 12 characters ")
```

error code:(invalid syntax)
it highlighted the space between the while and the len(password)

Comment: provide what error you got

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlfow! You will greatly increase your chances of getting an answer for your question if you include your input, what you have tried, your expected output vs. your actual output and the full stack trace of any errors you receive. You can also read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One issue I'm seeing is that you're not checking the lower bound and upper bound at the same time. If you enter a very long password, it will pass the first `while`, but ask for another input in the second while. You can then enter a short password and it's not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
password = str(input("Enter your password then press enter: "))

while not 6 < len(password) < 12 :
    password = str(input("Enter a password that is between 6 and 12 characters: "))
```

The first line gets the user's input **as a string** without a newline character.

The second and third lines act as a `do-while` loop, asking for input unless the the input's length is in the range (6,12).

Comment: that returned invalid syntax highlighting the .strip()

Comment: It shouldn't have... which version of python are you using?

Comment: I copied it in and im using python 3